# recently installed packages

Tags: centos, logging, yum

Is there anyway in `CentOS 6` to see the recent installed applications, at least those done by `yum`? Is there anything like a log-file by default?

If it is not available/enabled by default, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it should be in `/var/log/yum.log`.